# Как вывести в консоль каждое поле объекта внутри массива?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть массив вида

```
0: [{…}]
1: [{…}, {…}]
2: [{…}, {…}]
3: [{…}]
4: [{…}, {…}]
```

Как мне вывести в консоль каждое поле объекта внутри массива? Для примера, пусть поле называется Name.
Была такая попытка:

```
{this.state.customProducts &&
   this.state.customProducts.map((item) => {
    item.map((model) => {
     console.log(model.Name)
     return(<div>{model.Name}</div>)
    })
 })}
```

Получаю undefined.

Comment: а где вы пытаетесь вывести на консоль?

Comment: В обоих коллбеках map вы ничего не возвращаете

Comment: @AlexeyTen поправила код в вопросе, ситуацию это не меняет

Comment: Первый map всё ещё ничего не возвращает. И вы уверены что у вас там есть поле Name?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, есть

Comment: Не верю. Покажите `console.log(model)`

Comment: @AlexeyTen [{…}, {…}] это item, {…} это model. Уверяю Вас поле Nаme там есть

Comment: В таком случае уверяю вас, `console.log(model.Name)` работает.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Для каждого элемента массива можно использовать `console.table`.

```js
const a = [
  [{
    name:"test name",
    surname: "test surname"
  }],
  [{
    name: "test 2 ",
    surname: "test 2 surname"
  }]
];

a.forEach(el => console.table(el));
```

Answer (score 0):

помогла доп. проверка console.log(model && model.Name)

Comment: «Уверяю вас поле Name там есть» - хаха 

Comment: это проверка на наличие самого model

Answer (score -1):

Внутри объекта нужно пройтись по ключам, Object.keys вам в помощь. Т.е. первый цикл правильно, внутри Object.keys(item).forEach(key => console.log(item[key]));